# Logistics of living in EU and working for an US company

Tags: united-states, europe, remote-work

I’m a software engineer with almost 3 years of experience and I’ve been having a little look around the job market and I came across a full remote job from a credible company in the US. This would be on the payroll of the company (I think) so no freelance or anything.

They advertise a salary of around 130K a year, here in Belgium I earn around 40K.

It seems insane to me that I would earn 3x the amount I earn now for basically doing the same job.

Does anyone have any info/guidance about the logistics of working in the EU for an US company?

Not only about salary but also health insurance for example.

I’m planning to talk to an professional either way, but there I could also use your help. Who is a professional in this field? Would that be the bank? Our government?

Any info/experience on this topic would be amazing!

Comment: Taxes will be a nightmare. You will be taxed in both nations, which is typical of EU/USA, depending on tax treaty of course. Definitely don’t forget taxes.

Comment: If you don’t have a US SSN don’t bother researching more.

Comment: @drmrsthemonarch i did not forget, don't worry :). Was also part of the question if people got any extra insights

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are they explicitly saying they'll hire internationally for the role?  If not it's 99.9% certain that the position is only open to people in the USA.

Regulatory compliance is sufficiently complicated that effectively you can't work directly for a US company legally.  Your options would be:

1. They have a subsidiary in your country that would directly employ you.  This would be equivalent to working for any other local company.  You'd be paid in Euros and get all the standard benefits for anyone working in your country.
2. If you're hired as a contractor either directly as a self employed person.  You'd invoice them $X or €Y per hour (and you do need to make sure you know which currency the billing will be in - and thus who's paying the conversion costs and taking the exchange rate risk) and then be responsible for paying all local taxes/etc applicable to a 1 person company.
3. You could contract through an intermediary firm.  In this case they'd handle the accounting for you and may (in the US this can go both ways, I don't know what's permissible under your local labor law) provide some benefits to you as well.  In return for that they'd take a portion of what the US company is paying as a fee for their services.

Comment: They do state some stuff about timezones etc so i'm pretty sure they do want international people. I also saw they have an office in the Netherlands, maybe they would employ me there? I know working in the Netherlands from Belgium is fine, i know people here doing it. Thanks for the info!

Comment: If there's a localish office then 99% that's who you'd be employed by; and you can thank the EU for conditions that make it easy to work cross border there.

Comment: Okay awesome! Would also mean the salary will be more in line with what is expected here i suppose. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Probably, unless it's a big tech company that's throwing crazy amounts of money around globally.  $130k for a position with 3 years experience is high in most of the US.  (Silicon valley and NYC excepted.)